# From Neukirch 'algebraic number theory', normalization of a ring.Why $R'/IR'$ is quotient ring of $R'/aR'$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

This question is related to 'algebraic number theory' written by Neukirch, proof of lem $12.7$, the first line. It is used to prove well-known lemma to prove Krull-Akizuki theorem.

Let $R$ be a arbitrary commutative ring and $I$ be a nonzero ideal of $R$.
And let the normalization of $R$ (that is the  integral closure of $R$ in its field of fractions) be $R'$.

Then, why $R'/IR'$ is a quotient ring of $R'/aR'$($a∈I$)?

That is, for some $a_1,a_2∈I$, $R'/IR'$ is a quotient of $R'/a_1R'$ and $R'/a_2R'$?( I may have misunderstood the context of Neukirch)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since $a \in I$ lies in the kernel of $R \rightarrow R/I$, this factors as $R \rightarrow R/(a) \rightarrow R/I.$ Now $R/(a) \rightarrow R/I$ is surjective, hence $R/I$ is isomoprhic to a quotient of $R/(a).$

Comment: You need to exchange $R$ to $R'$. And why the map is injective ?

Comment: $R$ in my answer is just any ring, not necessarily normal. Since $\pi: R/I \rightarrow R/(a)$ is surjective (the map obtained in above answer), we obtain $R/I \cong (R/(a))/(ker(\pi)).$ Therefore $R/I$ is a quotient of $R/(a).$

Comment: Sorry to bother, I understood, Thank you for helping me.

Comment: No worries. I'm glad to be of help. In any case I am sorry if the tone in my answer was a bit harsh :D